# Clicking the Play button on the HomePage does not go to the GameSelectionPage

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, maui, android-mvvm

MauiProgram.cs

```
using MauiApp1.Sevices;
using MauiApp1.ViewModels;
using MauiApp1.Views;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MauiApp1;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();

#endif
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavigationService>();

        // UI
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<HomePage>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<GameSelectionPage>();

        // ViewModel
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<HomePageViewModel>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<GameSelectionPageViewModel>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

AppShell.xamls.cs

```
using MauiApp1.Views;

namespace MauiApp1;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(GameSelectionPage), typeof(GameSelectionPage));
    }
}
```

HomePage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewModels:HomePageViewModel"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.Views.HomePage">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Padding="0,250">
        <Label Text="Math Game"
               FontSize="30"
               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding HighScore}" />
        <Button Text="Play" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

HomePage.xaml.cs

```
using MauiApp1.Sevices;
using MauiApp1.ViewModels;

namespace MauiApp1.Views;

public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new HomePageViewModel(new NavigationService());
    }
}
```

HomePageViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using MauiApp1.Sevices;
using MauiApp1.Views;

namespace MauiApp1.ViewModels
{
    public class HomePageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private int _highScore;
        public int HighScore
        {
            get => _highScore;
            set
            {
                _highScore = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HighScore));
            }
        }

        public ICommand PlayCommand { get; }

        private INavigationService _navigationService;

        public HomePageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;

            PlayCommand = new Command(Play);
        }

        private void Play()
        {
            // Play butonuna tıklanınca yapılacak işlemler
            _navigationService.NavigateToAsync("GameSelectionPage");
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

NavigationService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MauiApp1.Views;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace MauiApp1.Sevices
{
    public interface INavigationService
    {
        Task NavigateToAsync(string pageName);
    }
    public class NavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _pageMap = new Dictionary<string, Type>
        {
            { "HomePage", typeof(HomePage) },
            { "GameSelectionPage", typeof(GameSelectionPage) },
            { "GamePage", typeof(GamePage) },
            { "GameOverPage", typeof(GameOverPage) }
            // add other page
        };

        public async Task NavigateToAsync(string pageName)
        {
            if (_pageMap.TryGetValue(pageName, out Type pageType))
            {
                Page page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Page with name {pageName} not found", nameof(pageName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the MVVM Design Pattern I am developing a basic operations math application. My app has all time high score info and a play button on the home page. After pressing the Play button, the user will choose which operation he wants to practice in basic mathematics (eg addition, subtraction, multiplication, division). But when I click the play button, my page does not change.

Comment: have you debugged it?  Is everything executed as expected?

Comment: Yes, no issues found.

Comment: I add something, can you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I created a demo and tried myself. But it works properly on my side.

You can refer to the following code :

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application 
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell();

    }
}
```

**AppShell.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp8152.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp8152"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}"
        Route="HomePage" />

</Shell>
```

**AppShell.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell 
{
      public AppShell()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

          Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(GameSelectionPage), typeof(GameSelectionPage));

    }
}
```

**MauiProgram.cs**

```
public static class MauiProgram 
{
      public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
      {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                  });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavigationService>();

        // UI
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<HomePage>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<GameSelectionPage>();

        // ViewModel
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<HomePageViewModel>();
        //builder.Services.AddTransient<GameSelectionPageViewModel>();

        return builder.Build();
      }
}
```

**Note:**

I've added some code that you didn't show, and the rest of the code is basically the same as yours.

Also, I removed some code on above code, for example, some pages and ViewModels that I didn't use in my demo.

Comment: I did the same as you did but still the button didn't work. I am very new to MAUI and MVVM and I am developing this project with the help of ChatGPT. Could it be because I'm using ready-made code? I mean maybe I need to change something somewhere to implement MVVM in the project.

Comment: Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem or more code snippets so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Comment: I manually coded all the steps one by one in a new project and this time it worked for me too.